# Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context

Tags: apex

I'm creating a Factory method that is Static and trying to call it from ctor but for some reason the compiler is blocking me with this error message 'Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context'

code

```
public with sharing virtual class PreviousFormDAO {
@TestVisible
protected PreviousFormDAO() {
    this.shPreviousForm = XXXXXXX;
}
public static PreviousFormDAO getFactoryPreviousFormDAO() {
    // code can only initialize the factory through this method
    if (PreviousFormDAO == null) {
        PreviousFormDAO = new PreviousFormDAO();
    }

    return PreviousFormDAO;
  }
}
```

Caller class

```
public with sharing class FormService {
PreviousFormDAO previousFormDAO;

public FormService() {
    this.previousFormDAO = PreviousFormDAO.getFactoryPreviousFormDAO();
}
```

it's only in this class we are getting the issue, but when we call it from another method it working as expected

Comment: have you looked up what the error means? it is fairly well documented, and there are several answers on this site explaining what it means.

Answer (score 5):

The general concept that caused this issue is called *shadowing*.

Apex, by and large, is case-insensitive aside from things that involve hashcodes like Sets and the keys of Maps, `String.contains()`, and perhaps a few other things I'm forgetting.

Identifiers (class names, variable names, method names) are also case-insensitive. This has caused other, similar issues for people in the past when they name a class `Test`, `Account`, etc...

Re-using identifiers introduces ambiguity, and compilers in general need to pick one interpretation (and always pick the same interpretation). The way Salesforce seems to resolve this is to:

1. see if an identifier is a valid variable, following the normal scoping rules
2. see if an identifier is an Apex class
3. see if an identifier is an SObject or system-provided class

That order is purely empirical. I do not know of any official documentation that can confirm/deny that.

So when you wrote `PreviousFormDAO previousFormDAO;`, you unknowingly locked yourself in to always treating `PreviousFormDAO` as a variable (inside your `FormService` class). This prevents you from accessing the static methods in your `PreviousFormDAO` class (because you'd always be accessing an instance of your class rather than referencing the class itself).

As you surmised, the solution/best practice here is to not name variables the same as the name of their class. You *can* get away with things like `Account account = new Account();` because the `SObject` class doesn't have any static methods (so Salesforce treating `account` as a variable isn't an issue, and there's enough context around `new Account();` for Salesforce to be able to compile that unambigously), but it's generally better to avoid that so as not to unnecessarily increase the cognitive load in reading your code.

As a quick final note, here's another short example of shadowing that you can  run via anonymous apex...

```java
Account Pattern = new Account();
// The Pattern class has a static method, 'compile()', and "Pattern" isn't a reserved
//   word
pattern.compile('a'); // Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void compile(String) from the type Account
```

Answer (score -3):

strange behaviour in SF complier as it's getting confused when the variable name and Class name have the same name but with lower-case in variable and upper-case in the first litter of the Class.

Solution: Use a totally different naming from the class name :blue_book: